# Maquetación html

Tags: html5, asp.net-mvc, xhtml

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto ASP.NET MVC, me encuentro maquetando el Layout, tengo la estructura de la maquetación en la cual en el header en una etiqueta section **deseo poner el icono del botón  de menú** y en una etiqueta aside que esta debajo del header deseo poner el cuerpo del menú despegable, muestro código.

Maquetación:

```
<body>
<header>
    <section id="menu"></section>
    <section id="banner"></section>
    <section id="user"></section>
    <section id="sesion"></section>
</header>
@*<nav></nav>*@
<main>
    <aside id="left">

    </aside>
    <article>

    </article>
</main>
<footer>

</footer>
```

Menu:

```
<div class="container demo-4">
    <div class="column">
        <div id="dl-menu" class="dl-menuwrapper">
            <button class="dl-trigger">Open Menu</button>
            <ul class="dl-menu">
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Mantenimiento</a>
                    <ul class="dl-submenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="Cliente/index">Cliente</a>
                            @*<ul class="dl-submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Shirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Jackets</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Chinos &amp; Trousers</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Underwear</a></li>
                            </ul>*@
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Articulo</a>
                            @*<ul class="dl-submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Jackets</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Knits</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Jeans</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Dresses</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Blouses</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">T-Shirts</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Underwear</a></li>
                            </ul>*@
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Proveedor</a>
                            @*<ul class="dl-submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Boys</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Girls</a></li>
                            </ul>*@
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Electronics</a>
                    <ul class="dl-submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Camera &amp; Photo</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">TV &amp; Home Cinema</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Phones</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">PC &amp; Video Games</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Furniture</a>
                    <ul class="dl-submenu">
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Living Room</a>
                            <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Sofas &amp; Loveseats</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Coffee &amp; Accent Tables</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Chairs &amp; Recliners</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Bookshelves</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Bedroom</a>
                            <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                <li>
                                    <a href="#">Beds</a>
                                    <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                        <li><a href="#">Upholstered Beds</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Divans</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Metal Beds</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Storage Beds</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Wooden Beds</a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#">Children's Beds</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="#">Bedroom Sets</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Chests &amp; Dressers</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Home Office</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Dining &amp; Bar</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Patio</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li>
                    <a href="#">Jewelry &amp; Watches</a>
                    <ul class="dl-submenu">
                        <li><a href="#">Fine Jewelry</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Fashion Jewelry</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Watches</a></li>
                        <li>
                            <a href="#">Wedding Jewelry</a>
                            <ul class="dl-submenu">
                                <li><a href="#">Engagement Rings</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Bridal Sets</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Women's Wedding Bands</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Men's Wedding Bands</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /dl-menuwrapper -->
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: ¿Cuál es el problema?

Comment: @GustavoGarcía, necesito poner el boton del menu en el seccion id=menu y el cuerpo del despegable en el aside left

Comment: @PedroÁvila y si dibujas usando Paint la idea que tienes en mente? Por lo que veo, le hace falta claridad a la pregunta :D

Answer (score 0):

Me parece que la solución que buscas está mas por el lado de javascript y css.

El botton lo podés implementar con un button, img,  con font-aweson, o con un link y darle estilo con css.

Luego con javascript o jquery podes engancharte al click del botón y ahí mostras o no el contenido en el aside también con jquery o con javascript.

Si el contenido es dinámico y no está presente en la página al momento del click, lo podés traer del server usando ajax que con jQuery es muy sencillo.

O por ahí no me quedó clara la pregunta.